# Spamassassin not scoring correctly

Tags: spam, spamassassin, spam-filter

I have Spamassassin running on a Ubuntu/Plesk server. It was working relatively well until recently but now seems to be letting through random spam messages.

These messages seem to trigger plenty of rules but the score is still coming in really low. I have lots of custom scores defined and they are very much on the high side because I don't mind a few false positives.

Here is and example of an email header run through Spamassassin that seems to clearly be spam:

`X-Spam-Status No, score=0.2 required=6.0 tests=BAYES_50,BODY_SPAM, HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_HI,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2, RCVD_IN_SBL,SPF_HELO_NONE,T_SPF_PERMERROR,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.4`

BODY_SPAM alone has a score of 2.0 as does BAYES_50

When I run `spamassassin -D --lint` it all seems fine. So I'm assuming my cf file is OK

Would be good to find out what causes this and if not at least how do I test or log Spamassassin.

Answer (score 1):

`RCVD_IN_DNSWL_HI` and `RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2` are *normally* considered *negative* indicators for spam, and carry a negative score. `RCVD_IN_DNSWL_HI` has a default score of -5.

So ending with a score of 0.2 sounds reasonable.

Comment: This would explain it. The list of default scores I have been using says RCVD_IN_DNSWL_HI gets a 0.0... Is there any way of showing all the scores implemented by Spamassassin.

Comment: https://spamassassin.apache.org/old/tests_3_3_x.html